# Start Mega Sub menu on hover from first `li` itself CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu on the website and it has sub menu also which open On hover.
Menu is working great but Sub menu is not starting from first li so that it can act as Mega menu.

I though it can be accomplished by below line

```
#ayurmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 0px;
}
```

But it is not working. Below is the link to JSFiddle. Please check.

[JS Fiddle here for Menu](http://jsfiddle.net/fwLgd99c/1/)

Ps: Also for About Us, sub menu shall start from same li, not from first li.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "Sub menu is not starting from first li"? Maybe you should explain what kind of end result you're expecting? "Mega Menu" has absolutely no meaning to me besides maybe a big ass menu. Also, the amount of CSS on that fiddle scares the crap out of me. I think the same result (as it currently is) could be achieved with half of it. But that's my oppinion..

Comment: @icecub ... start from first li means that sub menu shall start right beneath from Home tab. and can u rectify CSS also.. that wll be great help

Comment: I'll see if I can work something out. In the meantime I think Samuel gave you a pretty good answer to work with.

Comment: Well I did my best. Personally I think it looks better like this, but feel free to change it: https://jsfiddle.net/jzqe2j5k/

Comment: Oh. Only just noticed you've got some text decorations and hovering effects in there. Forgot those. But should be easy to add for you :)

Comment: @icecub ,... ur answer does not meet my expectations or u have just cleaned only CSS?

Comment: Well it wasn't an answer. Just a comment. And as I said, it wasn't finished yet. But ye, it uses a lot less css. With some modifications you could fairly easy make it the same as yours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` elements in the top level navigation (ie Home, Home Remedies, etc), can not have a relative position (`position:relative;`) to its parent ul.

You will need to make these `li` elements static. If you need the sub menu `li` elements to be relative then that's another story, but in order to push every to the left (under the first li), then the top level `li` elements need to be static.

http://jsfiddle.net/fwLgd99c/2/

Comment: I will try your answer samuel.. bt sub menu of  li shall not start from Home tab.. it shall start from same li only

Comment: i tried ur change wit some modifications and it works except about us tab.. here is link `http://jsfiddle.net/fwLgd99c/3/`